# Mac, iOS automation test from Terminal using instruments.app

Tags: macos, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I'm running iOS UIAutomation test from command line using the following command:

`instruments -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate  /Users/ctester/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestView-acwgjlejvnjkqietyevgfnsjngpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestView.app -e UIASCRIPT ta.js -e UIARESULTSPATH .`

The `TestView.app` got launched in simulator successfully, however the script won't run.

I tried specifying a nonexistent script, no error reported. So I guess argument `-e UIASCRIPT ta.js ...` is ignored.

The `instruments` command's version on my laptop is:

```
instruments, version 1.0
usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]
```

does it matter?

`TestView.app` and `ta.js` work just fine in instruments.app(GUI).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that instruments likes less than spaces in paths. If you DO have spaces in any of your path, escape them. Using quotes doesn't work reliably. While instruments may start up, it then chokes on the spaces later in the startup process.

Give instruments an absolute path to ta.js, and escape it. 
Example:

```
find ${PWD} -name ta.js -exec echo {} \; | sed 's/ /\\ /g'
```

The sed bit escapes the path of your found ta.js.

You can try:
    ``` instruments -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Users/ctester/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestView-acwgjlejvnjkqietyevgfnsjngpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestView.app -e UIASCRIPT ``find ${PWD} -name ta.js -exec echo {} \; | sed 's/ /\\ /g'`` -e UIARESULTSPATH . ```

But replace the double back ticks with single back ticks. ` is a reserved character in SO formatting :(

Comment: I am always careful with spaces, and absolute path still does not help. Have you ever tried it? Is the script got run in your case?

Comment: Yes, the above is working production code. Do you see any errors when you run instruments in verbose mode from the command line?

Comment: instead of that hack; quote your expansion properly.  "$(find "$PWD" -name ta.js)" (also, why did you toss in the -exec echo {} \;?)